# How to return object from native code to c#?

Tags: c#, android, java-native-interface, native

I am working on C# application in which I want to return object from native code to c#.
I did same thing using Android and JNI which is working fine, please find snippet below:

JNI CODE:

```
        JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_mpGetCurrentStatus(
                JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

            jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/nativeaudio/CurrentStatusDTO");
// calling constructor
            jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(JJI)V");
            jvalue args[3];
            args[0].j = 23; //value for size
            args[1].j = 50; //value for timestamp
            args[2].i = 100; //value for clipNote
            jobject object = (*env)->NewObjectA(env, cls, constructor, args);
            return object;
    }
```

Here is my DTO class CurrentStatusDTO.

```
public class CurrentStatusDTO {

    private long size;
    private long timestamp;
    private int clipNote;

    public CurrentStatusDTO(long size, long timestamp, int clipNote) {
        ...setting fields...
    }
    .....getters & setters.....
}
```

Android Code :

```
// declare native method
public native CurrentStatusDTO mpGetCurrentStatus(); 

// calling native method from some event.
CurrentStatusDTO currentStatus = mpGetCurrentStatus();
```

So, in android I am able to call native function which returns the object of CurrentStatusDTO.
Now, I want to do same thing using c#. Could you please help me in how to do this and how to write native code for c#?

Comment: What do you mean _native code_

Comment: native code means I want to do calculation in c/c++ code and want to call this code from c#.
As you can see I have written native code for android. so i want to do same for c#. so how to write same native c c++ code for c#.

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/) and try to implement what you need based on that. If you run into some specific problem during the process, then ask a question about _that_ (be sure to include all revelant information).